# How to modify the argument of a multi-argument macro?

Tags: c, macros, variadic-functions

I have various kinds of printf macros in my code defined along those lines:

```
#define DEBUG(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

This works well:

```
DEBUG("Hello %d",1);
```

will be the same as

```
printf("Hello %d",1);
```

Now can I make my macro also edit the args that are passed in to, say, add a \n at the end of the first argument?  I.e. so that

```
DEBUG("Hello %d",1);
```

turns into

```
printf("Hello %d\n",1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using:

```
#define DEBUG(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
```

The drawback is that you have to have at least one non-format string argument, i.e. you cannot use the macro as:

```
DEBUG("foo");
```

anymore.

For some compilers there are work-arounds allowing empty `__VA_ARGS__` like

```
#define DEBUG(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

in gcc (thanks to M. Oehm).

Comment: There are compiler-dependent solutions to the empty argument list, for example the `##__VA_ARGS__` syntax in gcc, but they are not portable, of course.

Comment: @MOehm: If multiple `printf()` statements are okay, then it could also be split into two to resolve the `fmt` issue: `#define DEBUG(...) do { printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n"); } while(0)`.

Comment: @TimČas: Yes, there is already Jean Jung's answer suggesting exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your `\n` to be always on the final, you can just add one more `printf` statement:

```
#define DEBUG(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n")
...
DEBUG("hello %d", 1);
DEBUG("hello %d", 1);
```

Outputs:

> hello 1
>
> hello 1

As pointed out by the others, this won't work as expected with this scenario:

```
if (cond) 
    DEBUG("Blah")
```

So you will have to define the macro this way:

```
#define DEBUG(...) do { printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n"); } while(0)
```

Thanks to M. Oehm and undur_gongor

Comment: Good idea, but you should wrap the two separate calls with the so that they act like a single function. Otherwise code like `if (cond) DEBUG("Hey!")` won't work as intended.

Comment: The common way to do that is `#define DEBUG(...) do { printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n"); } while(0)`

Comment: `printf("\n");` is equivalent to `puts("");`

Comment: Another workaround to the no-argument problem is to just have two macros (e.g. `DEBUG` for arguments and `DEBUG0` if only a string)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with string literal concatenation, if you know that the first argument is always a string literal.

If you have a macro

```
#define EXAMPLE(A,B) \
printf("%s", A B)
```

then in code

```
EXAMPLE("foo ", "bar\n");
```

would be the same as

```
printf("%s", "foo bar\n");
```

(Since you didn't show full code, I assume you can adapt this to your case)